# Passing data from Activity to Fragment (by accessing activity from fragment) giving Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There are so many ways but i am using this one:

Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String myString = "hello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ...
}

public String getMyData() {
    return myString;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Main2Activity activity = (Main2Activity ) getActivity();
    String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
    return view;
}
}
```

BUT its giving me class cast exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dev03.xyz.Activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.MyActivity
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.Main2Activity

-- Package is same

Thanks

Comment: Show me your code where you set the fragment.

Comment: Are you using support libraries?

Comment: On what activity do you set fragment?

Comment: @Nfear - Yes ksoap2 and universal , but in other activities and fragments.

Comment: @Masum - you want the XML file where i set the fragment or you need .java file code. Sorry new one here

Comment: I have one MainActivity.java in this i have pager for fragment say (Fragment1.java). I have one another activity (Main2Activity.java).  I want to pass data from Main2Activity to Fragment1.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object of MainActivity2 and simply access your method:

```
  MainActivity2 mn2=new ManiActivity2();
  mn2.getMyData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your fragment in MainActivity and want to cast in MyActivity. That's why it is showing ClassCastException

Comment: but situation is same. open you fragment in Main2Activity not in MainActivity

Comment: But i want to use the Main2Activity.java result in MyFragment.java.May be i am not getting your point . can u jus give a small example

Answer (score 0):

Changing from android.app.Fragment to support.v4.app.Fragment this.

Comment: Fragment is already extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "StackOverFlow");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass stackOverflow = new Fragmentclass();
stackOverflow.setArguments(bundle);
```

In Fragments > onCreateView Method.

```
String strName = getArguments().getString("name");
```